# How can i shoot accelerated electron directly into the air?

Tags: particle-physics, wavelength, x-rays, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

I am trying to do an experiment in which I have to first accelerate the electron to 10eV and then shoot into the air directly. I need some kind of membrane which allows electron to pass
and keep vacuum on the accelerator's side and air on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

When you shoot electrons into the air, the result is a spark. It takes a much higher voltage than $10$ V to do this. You don't get spontaneous sparks off a $10$ V battery.

The reason is that air is an insulator.

Metals are conductors. Electrons flow freely around inside a metal. This is because some electrons do not remain strongly attached to an individual atom. Instead they spread out in the metal. This leaves positively charged atoms. These attract the electrons. So the electrons move about freely, but stay uniformly spread out and still near the atoms. The attraction makes it hard for them to leave the metal.

You can still have a current in a wire. In a closed circuit, electrons are pushed into one end of a wire, and pulled out of the other. The number of electrons in the wire does not change. It is like water flowing in a pipe. The pipe is always full, water goes in one end and comes out the other.

Air does not have this property of allowing atoms to wander freely. Atoms in air are stuck firmly to individual atoms.

However at high enough voltage, typically thousands of volts, electrons have enough energy where they do fly out of the metal and into the air. Furthermore, they hit air molecules hard enough to know electrons off. This makes enough unattached, freely flowing electrons that a current does flow through the ionized air. This is a spark.

---

Edit

It just occurred to me. You said $10$eV. Did you mean $10$keV? That would change things.

---

Edit 2

You have some misconceptions. 10eV is a very low energy electron. But even a high energy electron won't penetrate anything strong enough to withstand vacuum.

For example, xray tubes generate xrays by accelerating electrons to high energy. $60$ keV might be typical. The electrons generate xrays when they slam into a stationary target. An xray tube often has a very thin (~$1 \mu$m  thick) beryllium window. This is strong enough to withstand vacuum, but fairly transparent to xrays. $60$ keV electrons do not penetrate it.

You may do better not having then electron bean penetrate into air. Just work in vacuum. See the [Crookes tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_tube)

Comment: What if you try with thermionic emission? How much voltage would you need?

Comment: Ionization energy of oxygen and nitrogen is 13 and 15 eV and for ionization them in air it need mean 35 eV energy to generate ion. My question was that I have to first accelerate electron in vacuum and then shoot into the air so ''I need to know about any kind of membrane which allows electron to pass through itself but don't allows air exchange"

Comment: 'I need to know about any kind of membrane which allows electron to pass through itself but don't allows air exchange" There is none. Any membrane will have a lattice of atoms composed of an enormous number, (avogadro's number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant)zillions of atoms and molecules interconnected with fields strong enough to deflect/reflect  any ev energy  electron.

Comment: similar to bullet fired on a wood block comes out with less energy , i want to shoot high energy electron on an material and need an electron of 10eV coming out of that electron so, i need to calculate:

Comment: need to calculate what should be the penetration of electron and loss of kinetic energy of electron inside the material. please assist me

Comment: if you shoot electrons of any energy through matter you get not a single energy of 10eV. Maybe you tell us, why you want 10eV in air?

Comment: For selective ionization of components of air.